# Command Line - Remove in folder with regex windows

Tags: regex, windows, unix, sapui5

### Objective

How can I remove all files within a folder (recursively) with regex on File Name?

From Windows 10, I can use PowerShell or git console with unix commands.

### Required points

- NOT Matches `/.+?-dbg.*?\.js/`
- For a file to be matched it's required to match a "brother file" with the previous point pattern.

### Example Test Folder contains

- ActionMode.js
- ActionMode-dbg.js
- Component.js
- Component-dbg.js
- DualContribution.controller.js
- DualContribution-dbg.controller.js
- resources.js
- manifest-json

### Files that would be deleted

- ActionMode.js
- Component.js
- DualContribution.controller.js

If you need more information please ask me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know whether this really helps you, but here is a quick solution.
This Autoit code prints all files to console that you want to delete.

```
#include <Array.au3>
#include <File.au3>
#include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>
$allFiles = _FileListToArrayRec(@ScriptDir, '*.js', $FLTAR_FILES,   $FLTAR_RECUR , $FLTAR_SORT, $FLTAR_FULLPATH  )

If @error Then ConsoleWrite(@error & @crlf)
_ArrayDisplay($allFiles, "Sorted tree")

For $i = 0 to UBound($allFiles) -1
    If StringInStr($allFiles[$i], '-dbg') <> 0 Then
        If StringReplace($allFiles[$i], '-dbg', '') == $allFiles[$i-1] Then ConsoleWrite('Delete file: ' & $allFiles[$i-1] & @CRLF)
    EndIf
Next
```

Comment: Is AutoIt similar to autohotkey? I am more used to AHK, how can I execute this script? can you share me a reference atleast? thanks.

Comment: https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/ Scite is the preferred IDE:Yes, it is similiar to AHK and vba.